# How do I limit a GameObject to jump only Once?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have Googled Everything but cannot get the right results. I want the GameObject to only jump once in the air, come back to the ground and then the player can jump. My current results are that the GameObject flies in the air if you press the spacebar. I wanna limit the GameObject to jump only once, come back and then jump if the player desires to. I have Shown some code down`

```
public class SphereController : MonoBehaviour
{
private bool IsOnGround = true;
Rigidbody rb;
public float BallSpeed = 10f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float Hmove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float Vmove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 MoveBall = new Vector3(Hmove, 0f, Vmove);
    rb.AddForce(MoveBall * BallSpeed);

    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) && IsOnGround == true)
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 20, 0);
        
    }


}

private void OnCollisionStay()
{
    IsOnGround = true;
}
```

Comment: `Input.GetKey` tells you if the key is pressed, but only if it happens to be pressed the moment you call the function. It's best for games where the user holds a key down. If you want to capture a keypress event, handle the [event](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.KeyDownEvent.html).

Answer (score 1):

Change the `IsOnGround` to false.

```
if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) && IsOnGround)
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 20, 0);
        IsOnGround = false
    }
```

You have the OnCollision method that changes it back to true so this should work fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

So, the way I do it is the following.

STEPS:

1- Tag the floor object as whatever you like. I always tag it as ground. You tag objects in the Inspector window, at the top left. I says Untagged by default

2- This is the Code I write:

```
 bool isGrounded;
 
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
 {
          if(other.gameObject.tag == "ground")
          {
                     isGrounded = true; // if its colliding with "ground", isGrounded  is true
          }
          else
          {
                     isGrounded = false;
          }
          if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.space) && isGrounded) // change space to whatever key to jump
          {
                    Jump(); // your jump code goes here EG. Rigidbody.AddForce(0, 15, 0);
          }
 }
```

I hope this is helpful.